# How does one approach this challenge asked in an Amazon Interview?

Tags: dictionary, graph, dynamic-programming, memoization, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am struggling optimising this past amazon Interview question involving a DAG.

This is what I tried (The code is long and I would rather explain it)-

1. Basically since the graph is a DAG and because its a transitive relation a simple traversal for every node should be enough.
2. So for every node I would by transitivity traverse through all the possibilities to get the end vertices and then compare these end vertices to get
   the most noisy person.
3. In my second step I have actually found one such (maybe the only one) most noisy person for all the vertices of the traversal in step 2. So I memoize all of this in a mapping and mark the vertices of the traversal as visited.
4. So I am basically maintaining an adjacency list for the graph, A visited/non visited mapping and a mapping for the output (the most noisy person for every vertex).
5. In this way by the time I get a query I would not have to recompute anything (in case of duplicate queries).

The above code works but since I cannot test is with testcases it may/may not pass the time limit. Is there a faster solution(maybe using DP) to this. I feel I am not exploiting the transitive and anti symmetric condition enough.

Obviously I am not checking the cases where a person is less wealthy than the current person. But for instance if I have pairs like - (1,2)(1,3)(1,4)...etc and maybe (2,6)(2,7)(7,8),etc then if I am given to find a more wealthy person than 1 I have traverse through every neighbor of 1 and then the neighbor of every neighbor also I guess. This is done only once as I store the results.

[Question Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q231q.jpg)

[Question Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mNZd.jpg)

Edit(Added question Text)-

Rounaq is graduating this year. And he is going to be rich. Very rich. So rich that he has decided to have 
a structured way to measure his richness. Hence he goes around town asking people about their wealth, 
and notes down that information. 
Rounaq notes down the pair (Xi; Yi) if person Xi has more wealth than person Yi. He also notes down 
the degree of quietness, Ki, of each person. Rounaq believes that noisy persons are a nuisance. Hence, for 
each of his friends Ai, he wants to determine the most noisy(least quiet) person among those who have 
wealth more than Ai. 
Note that "has more wealth than"is a transitive and anti-symmetric relation. Hence if a has more wealth 
than b, and b has more wealth than c then a has more wealth than c. Moreover, if a has more wealth than 
b, then b cannot have more wealth than a. 
Your task in this problem is to help Rounaq determine the most noisy person among the people having 
more wealth for each of his friends ai, given the information Rounaq has collected from the town.
Input 
First line contains T: The number of test cases 
Each Test case has the following format:

N

K1 K2 K3 K4 : : : Kn

M

X1 Y1

X2 Y2

. . .

. . .

XM YM

Q

A1

A2

. . .

. . .

AQ

N: The number of people in town

M: Number of pairs for which Rounaq has been able to obtain the wealth 
information

Q: Number of Rounaq’s Friends

Ki: Degree of quietness of the person i

Xi; Yi: The pairs Rounaq has noted down (Pair of distinct values)

Ai: Rounaq’s ith friend

For each of Rounaq’s friends print a single integer - the degree of quietness of the most noisy person as required or -1 if there is no wealthier person for that friend.

Comment: Please include the problem description as text in the body of your question (links to outside images can later break, leaving the question unintelligible).

Comment: @גלעדברקן Thanks for the suggestion...have added the question text

Comment: @גלעדברקן why did you remove the answer

Comment: -Now updated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on the pairs `X`, `Y`. Then iterate from the most wealthy down the the least wealthy, and store the most noisy person seen so far:

```
less wealthy    ->    most wealthy
<- person with lowest K so far <-
```

Then for each query, binary search the first person with greater wealth than the friend. The value we stored is the most noisy person with greater wealth than the friend.

#### UPDATE

It seems that we cannot rely on the data allowing for a complete topological sort. In this case, traverse sections of the graph that lead from known greatest to least wealth, storing for each person visited the most noisy person seen so far. The example you provided might look something like:

```
  3 - 5
 /    |
1 - 2 |
   /  |
  4 --
```

Traversals:

```
1 <- 3 <- 5
1 <- 2
4 <- 2
4 <- 5
```

(Input)

```
2 1
2 4
3 1
5 3
5 4
8 2 16 26 16
```

(Queries and solution)

```
 3  4  3  5  5 
16  2 16 -1 -1
```

Comment: I am confused. Firstly the most noisy person has the least K value. Also the question does not say who the most wealthy person is. It just gives a comparison between a pair. So your method works perfect if we know the exact order of wealthy to less wealthy vertices. If we consider the sample case - We have one of the topological sort as 1,3,4,2,5. and if we iterated backwards we get 5,2,2,2,2 as the most noisy (least k) traversal. Now if we get 3 as the query we find 4 to be the one next to 3 but what is stored is 2 as the K value but actually the answer should be 16 for query 3.

Comment: If we know between vertex 5 and 2 which is more wealthier then your method works perfect.

Comment: @PriyankaSinha ah, thank's for clarifying. So we don't know the complete ordering. Let me think about it.

Comment: But what happens in the traversal 1,3,5 and 1,2. 1 now has 5 and 2 to compare. In this case we get only two such vertices(5 and 2) but what happens when this graph grows bigger and we get multiple paths emanating from 1. To traverse all these paths would make it complex like I tried. Is there a neater situation @גלעדברקן ?

Comment: Maybe with Dynamic Programming on a recurrence. The problem with topological sort is a that it is not unique.

Comment: @PriyankaSinha cases where multiple paths lead to one lowest vertex make sense if we don't have a complete ordering. I don't see how the total number of edges in all the traversals can be more than the total number of edges (`M`). That does not seem too much. Could you present a counter example?

Comment: Yes you are right ... I can't think of a counter example. Since it's a DAG traversing through all edges should be fine :)